# MySQL Получить первую запись из группы

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица в которой куча строк с переводом на разные языки. Нужно сделать выборку типа

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE language_id = @language_id
```

но с граблями: не для всех языков есть перевод нужной строки. В таком случае нужно получить или первую запись с учётом значимости языка (например `ru, en, by, ua, kz`, другие) или хотя бы просто первую запись с другим `language_id`.
Как это реализовать?

Comment: Спасибо, подсказка про ORDER BY FIELD(language_id, 'ru', 'en', 'by', 'ua', 'kz') помогла
Для OpenCart работает вот такой запрос
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT `category`.parent_id as parent_category_id, `category_description`.category_id, `language`.`code`, `category_description`.`name`
FROM `category_description`
INNER JOIN `category` ON `category`.category_id = `category_description`.category_id
JOIN `language` ON `language`.language_id = `category_description`.language_id
ORDER BY `category_description`.category_id, FIELD(`language`.`code`, 'en', 'ru', 'az') DESC
) myViewTable
GROUP BY category_i

Answer (score 1):

> > куча строк с переводом на разные языки.

Значит в таблице есть ключ, по которому проиходит "перевод"
я бы сделал как то так:

```
$stack = array('ru', 'en', 'by', 'ua', 'kz');
$q = $db->query('select * from table where translation_key=@key and language_id in ("ru", "en", "by", "ua", "kz")', array('@key' => $yourKey));
$translations = array();
foreach ($q as $tr) {
    $translations[$tr['language_id']] = $r['translate_value'];
}

// ищем первое наличие перевода. исходя из пордка языков установленных в $stack
foreach ($stack as $lang) {
    if (!empty($translations[$lang])) return $translations[$lang];
}

throw new Exception('no translate for '.$yourKey);
```

Также это можно сделать и с помощью mysql

например как то так:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE translation_key=@key and language_id in ("ru", "en", "by", "ua", "kz" ORDER BY FIELD(language_id, 'ru', 'en', 'by', 'ua', 'kz');
```

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так

```
SELECT sentence_id, 
       FIRST_ROW(text) OVER (
        PARTITION BY sentence_id 
        ORDER BY (case p.id = @language_id then 1 else 1+ gp.priority end)
       )
  from translation t,
       lang_priority p
 where t.language_id = p.id
```

[Подробнее можно почитать тут](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/10/analytic-functions-first_value-last_value-lead-lag/)